# Python 3 - List and Dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Considering the google maps API output shown bellow I tried to get values using Python dict methods but I got an error saying: `"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'"`

```
{
    "address_components": [
        {
            "long_name": "1",
            "short_name": "1",
            "types": [
                "street_number"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Amphitheatre Parkway",
            "short_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
            "types": [
                "route"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Mountain View",
            "short_name": "Mountain View",
            "types": [
                "locality",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Santa Clara County",
            "short_name": "Santa Clara County",
            "types": [
                "administrative_area_level_2",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "California",
            "short_name": "CA",
            "types": [
                "administrative_area_level_1",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "United States",
            "short_name": "US",
            "types": [
                "country",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "94043",
            "short_name": "94043",
            "types": [
                "postal_code"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "1326",
            "short_name": "1326",
            "types": [
                "postal_code_suffix"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "1 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
    "geometry": {
        "location": {
            "lat": 37.4268042,
            "lng": -122.0806179
        },
        "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport": {
            "northeast": {
                "lat": 37.4281531802915,
                "lng": -122.0792689197085
            },
            "southwest": {
                "lat": 37.4254552197085,
                "lng": -122.0819668802915
            }
        }
    },
    "place_id": "ChIJZeH1dve5j4AR0RvMuo9xdlk",
    "plus_code": {
        "compound_code": "CWG9+PQ Mountain View, California, United States",
        "global_code": "849VCWG9+PQ"
    },
    "types": [
        "street_address"
    ]
}
```

Here is the code I've used:

```
results = gmaps.reverse_geocode((37.4267861, -122.0806032))
out = list(results.values())
print(out)
```

When I look for the type in results variable using `print(type(results))` I got it is a list. `<class 'list'>.` If I have keys and values in the above output, why it is considered a list instead of a dict?

I have read about the differences between List and Dict in python, and one of them is precisely that Dict is unordered and have a pair [key][value] and Lists are ordered ones, and you can access values using an Index.

How is the best approach to get, e.g., 'United States' and 'CA' from the results above?

Cheers,

Comment: Its probably list of dict. So try doing `results[0]['address_components']`. Or if it is json string look into json parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `results` is the output you print in the beginning of your question, you don't need to try go get `results.values()` let alone put it in yet another list.

`results` may be a list containing dictionaries (though it definitely looks like it's not in a list when I look at your data). And your dictionaries have lists in them.

You can either access a specific value e.g.:

```
print(results[0]["address_components"][3]["types"][1]) # should print 'political'
```

You can also try this:

```
for r in results:              # Loop over all items in the list `results`
    for key, val in r.items(): # Loop over all key value pairs in `r`
        print(key)             # Print key
        # Whatever you want to do here
```

Otherwise, you can print a json formatted tree by simply running:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(results, indent=4))
```

Or if you want to make a more compact list, try this recursive function:

```
def parse(data, indent=0):
    if not isinstance(data, list):
        data = [data]

    for d in data:
        if not isinstance(d, dict):
            print(" "*4*indent + d)
            continue

        for key, val in d.items():
            if isinstance(val, list) or isinstance(val, dict):
                print("{}{}" .format(
                    " "*4*indent, key))
                parse(val, indent + 1)
            else:
                print("{}{}{}{}" .format(
                    " "*4*indent, key, " "*(38-len(key)-4*indent), val))

parse(results)
```

The last solution gives you the following output:

```
address_components
    long_name                         1
    short_name                        1
    types
        street_number
    long_name                         Amphitheatre Parkway
    short_name                        Amphitheatre Pkwy
    types
        route
    long_name                         Mountain View
    short_name                        Mountain View
    types
        locality
        political
    long_name                         Santa Clara County
    short_name                        Santa Clara County
    types
        administrative_area_level_2
        political
    long_name                         California
    short_name                        CA
    types
        administrative_area_level_1
        political
    long_name                         United States
    short_name                        US
    types
        country
        political
    long_name                         94043
    short_name                        94043
    types
        postal_code
    long_name                         1326
    short_name                        1326
    types
        postal_code_suffix
formatted_address                     1 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA
geometry
    location
        lat                           37.4268042
        lng                           -122.0806179
    location_type                     ROOFTOP
    viewport
        northeast
            lat                       37.4281531802915
            lng                       -122.0792689197085
        southwest
            lat                       37.4254552197085
            lng                       -122.0819668802915
place_id                              ChIJZeH1dve5j4AR0RvMuo9xdlk
plus_code
    compound_code                     CWG9+PQ Mountain View, California, United States
    global_code                       849VCWG9+PQ
types
    street_address
```

Answer (score 1):

In your output, you have a dictionary which contains a list which contains others dictionaries
To access United states, you have to do that :

```py
print(out['address_components'][5]['long_name'])
```